# How to debug a JS file locally in the client machine

Tags: javascript

There is a CGI webserver and this webserver pushes certain html files + JS files when we browse the URL.

I want to work on some bugs on the JS file that is being pushed from the server.
The normal way is to replace JS file directly in webserver and rebrowse the URL to see the effect of the change.

Is there a way in which I can change the JS file alone locally (i.e on client machine / browser) and check whether the fix / code change is proper, do UT etc and finally push that into webserver for full round of testing?

It is possible?

Comment: Yes. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: @Jonathan Yes I tried to use it. However when I refresh the URL to see the change,  the JS is getting pushed from server instead of reloading the locally saved JS

Comment: You can do that with Workspaces. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces

Comment: I think NO. chrome workspace just allow files to be edited via browser. My question is different. I would like to cut down the time wasted on going back & forth to the webserver inorder to fix a logic issue in JS files. Since JS files are completely running in client, I was hoping for a way to test the changes done in JS locally, rather than going to server everytime for unit testing

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple options:

**1. Use Chrome dev tools** 
As pointed out above, just change the file in Chrome developer console: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging. This may or may not work depending on the changes you need to make

**2. Set up a server locally for testing. You can set one up fairly easily using http-server from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server.**

```
npm install http-server -g
```

Then in the root directory with all your HTML/JS files, and just run

```
http-server
```

You can then test locally by pointing your browser to http://localhost.

Comment: Yes I tried to use Chrome dev tools. However when I refresh the URL to see the change, the JS is getting pushed from server instead of reloading the locally saved JS

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to debug but you can use the console of the browser to check for errors.

- [Chrome debugging tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)
- [FireFox debugging tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript)
- [Opera Mini debugging tools](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/)

If you want to go into more advanced stuff, you can look into [GulpJs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for task automation and install plugins like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/) for Js Debugging. What you can do with GulpJs is watch the js files for any changes and do something specific. So if there is any mistake, js-hint will tell you in the CLI. An Example I did this morning from a tutorial is below:

install gulp

```
npm install gulp -g
```

Install JS-hint

```
npm install gulp-jshint --save-dev
```

create a `gulpfile.js` file and write this in it:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
//call JsHint plugin
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');


// JS hint task
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});
gulp.watch('./src/scripts/*.js', function() {
    gulp.run('jshint', 'scripts');
});
//automate tasks
// default gulp task
gulp.task('default', ['scripts'],function() {
});
```